# <div> element is flowing off the top of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, resize

Problem is demonstrated below:

1. The problem is very apparent when the button is clicked - the top of the page can no longer be seen. The vertical scrollbar appears, but doesn't allow you to scroll far enough up. I would expect (want) the heading to be shifted to the top of the page, but no further.
2. The problem is present even without clicking the button - resize the window small enough, and you again lose some of the page.

I suspect that the problem stems from the way that the flex boxes are being used, but I haven't been able to find a way to fix this. Possible that the resize function is causing the problem, but that wouldn't explain the second point above (would it?).

Ideally, I would want the vertical scrollbar to appear (on window resize and / or button click) to allow the user to still see the entire contents of the page. The first div (containing the title) would then be "pushed" right up against the top of the page.

```js
function collapseSection(element) {
  // get the height of the element's inner content, regardless of its actual size
  var sectionHeight = element.scrollHeight;

  // temporarily disable all css transitions
  var elementTransition = element.style.transition;
  element.style.transition = '';

  // on the next frame (as soon as the previous style change has taken effect),
  // explicitly set the element's height to its current pixel height, so we
  // aren't transitioning out of 'auto'
  requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    element.style.height = sectionHeight + 'px';
    element.style.transition = elementTransition;

    // on the next frame (as soon as the previous style change has taken effect),
    // have the element transition to height: 0
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      element.style.height = 0 + 'px';
    });
  });

  // mark the section as "currently collapsed"
  element.setAttribute('data-collapsed', 'true');
}

function expandSection(element) {
  // get the height of the element's inner content, regardless of its actual size
  var sectionHeight = element.scrollHeight;

  // have the element transition to the height of its inner content
  element.style.height = sectionHeight + 'px';

  // when the next css transition finishes (which should be the one we just triggered)
  element.addEventListener('transitionend', function(e) {
    // remove this event listener so it only gets triggered once
    element.removeEventListener('transitionend', arguments.callee);

    // remove "height" from the element's inline styles, so it can return to its initial value
    element.style.height = null;
  });

  // mark the section as "currently not collapsed"
  element.setAttribute('data-collapsed', 'false');
}

document.querySelector('#toggle-button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // var section = document.querySelector('.section.collapsible');
  var section = document.getElementById("ohhai");
  var isCollapsed = section.getAttribute('data-collapsed') === 'true';

  if (isCollapsed) {
    expandSection(section);
    section.setAttribute('data-collapsed', 'false');
  } else {
    collapseSection(section);
    section.setAttribute('data-collapsed', 'true');
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #636b6f;
  font-weight: 100;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.slide-open {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100vh;
}

.flex-center {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.position-ref {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}

.links>a {
  color: #636b6f;
  padding: 0 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.email>a {
  color: #636b6f;
  padding: 0 25px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
    <div class="content">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="m-b-md" style="font-size: 84px; margin-bottom: 30px;">
            What a Heading!
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="links">
            <a>sub-point 1</a>
            <a>sub-point 2</a><br>
            <a>sub-point 3</a>
            <a>sub-point 4</a>
            <a>sub-point 5</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">&nbsp;</div>

        <div id="ohhai" class="col-12 slide-open" style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; min-height: 0 !important; height: 0; " data-collapsed="true">
          <div class="links">
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
            <a>some nice blurb about things...</a><br>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="email">
            <a>oh@hai.lolz</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12">&nbsp;</div>
      <button id="toggle-button">toggle</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

View on [Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/pEy5DYDwf9)

Answer (score 0):

Removing .full-height did the job.

Doesn't seem to be important either

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line:

```
.flex-center {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: That class might be used elsewhere... maybe just remove it from the specific `<div>` in question.

Comment: @showdev Agreed.  he must select specific dev and apply css for that div only.

Comment: Thank you - that does resolve the scrolling issue, but the content is no longer vertically centered. Tried some of the suggested "Bootstrappy" methods (like replacing the first 3 divs in the body with `<div class="container d-flex h-100"><div class="row justify-content-center align-content-center content">` but same problem. Sure I'm missing something simple...just not seeing it...

Comment: have you tried positioning that to absolute and top:0 I think that will do the job.